# Have always a margin-bottom of 10px below my last list item "See more links"

Tags: html, css

I have 4 columns in my footer.

My column at right have some list items, and my last list item “See more links”, when I click in it Im changing my first list of items to other list using jQuery slideToggle().

But using this slideToggle, Im with, when I click in “See more links” my footer goes up a bit and then down again.

This problem was solved using in my column div (#col), max-height:227px; and min-height:227px; proprierties.

The problem Im having now is, that I want always margin-bottom of just 10px of my last item “See more links”, but Im having different margins in different browsers and different resolutions.

Do you know how can I solve this? Im trying to “play” with position absolute or a container with fixed height, but Im not able to have the same result in different browsers and resolutions.

I have my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/vb63n9vg/4/

My html:

```
<footer id="footer-container">
    <section id="footer1">
        <div id="col" class="col4" style="margin-right:0;">
            <h1>LINKS</h1>
            <ul id="list1">                
                <li><a href="#"><span>Link 0</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Link 1</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Link 2</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Link 3</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Link 4</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="change_links1" class="toggle">see more links</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="list2"> 
                <li><a href="#"><span>Link 0</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Link 1</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Link 2</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Link 3</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Link 4</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="change_links2" class="toggle">Ver mais Links</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="footer2-container">
        <div id="footer2">
            <p class="copyright">&copy; copyright</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</footer>
```

My css:

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;}

#list2
{
    display:none;
}

#footer-container
{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    float:left; 
    background:#ff9900;
    border-top:0;
} 
#footer1
{
    width:1160px;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}


#footer1 ul 
{
    list-style:none; 
}

#footer1 ul li
{
    margin:0 0 7px 0;
}

#footer1 ul li a 
{   
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#444;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size:15px;
}

#footer1 ul li a:hover
{
    color:#fff;
}

#col
{
    float:left;
    margin-right:40px; 
    margin:10px 53px 10px 0;
    width:250px;
    max-height:227px;
    min-height:227px;
}

#footer2-container
{
    width:100%;     
    float:left;
    background:#ECECEA;
    border-top:0;
    border-top: 2px solid #e0e0e0;
}

#footer2
{
    width:1160px;
    margin:10px auto 10px auto;
    background:#ECECEA;
    height:40px;

}

#footer2 .copyright
{
    float:left; 
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; 
    color:#2F3083; 
    font-size:14px; 
    line-height:40px;
}
```

Comment: instead of setting the min and max heights, why don't you set only the height?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want a consistent distance of an item inside your column container and the bottom of the container itself, what you want is:

```
#col
{
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to use the last-child selector. Then you won't need to add a class to the last element in the html.

```
#footer1 ul li:last-child
{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```